# How to replace kaltura embedded flash player with JW player

Tags: jwplayer, kaltura

I am new with kaltura and i want to know, is there any way to replace kaltura player with jw player in CE 5.0 .
If anyone has done this before please tell me how i can replace kaltura embedded player with my JW player.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you mean you want to use the JW Player inside of your Kaltura Dashboard?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no option to use the JW Player inside of Kaltura, there is no longer an official integration between the two. You should probably email Kaltura support about this if you really want the JW player though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to integrate on the playing sources level, you could [grab flavor urls](http://player.kaltura.com/docs/getSources) and just play them with whatever web player you like.

But to leverage [all of the player functionality](http://player.kaltura.com/docs/) that ties into the kaltura platform; access controls, tagged flavor selection, plugin config etc, you of course need to use the kaltura player proper.